# How add number and empty line in powershell to existing text file?

Tags: powershell

How can I add number 1, 2, 3.... before each two lines of text and then empty line in powershell?

[image]

Comment: could you show a sample of your start file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$i = 0

Get-Content -Path $File -ReadCount 2 |
ForEach-Object {
    $i++
    $i
    $_
    ''
}
```